# How often Google App Marketplace update their search indexing

Tags: google-search, google-apps-marketplace, chrome-web-store

We modified the description for our app in Google App Marketplace, and its updated but when I search for a keyword(which is in the description part) for my app  it's not listed in search results

How does the search work in Google App Marketplace?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the behaviour of a thirty party application instead of directly about programming or coding.

Comment: @Pang it may not be technical but it's useful. Stackoverflow is for programmers and the doubt is by a developer which is surely useful for others too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no definite document that mentions on how often the search index for the Google Apps Marketplace refreshes. But in my opinion, I think after modifying detail(s) of your app, it will again be subject for the same review process the same way as publishing an app for the first time.

You probably have read this before, but just in case other people from the community might need it, here are the [Steps to Publish an App in Google Apps Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/listing#steps_to_publish_the_app).